# For loop on javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this javascript object:

```
var input = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'michael',
        favorite: 'bmw'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'steve',
        favorite: 'bentley'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'denise',
        favorite: 'ford'
    },
]
```

And this is my function, it is supposed to loop through `input` and when called with `console.log` print a specific favorite, depending on which element on the list has been read by the loop.

```
findYourFavorite = function() {
    for(let x=0; x<3; x++) {
        if(input[x].title) {
            var response = input[x].favorite
        }
    }
    return response
}
```

If I run  `console.log(findYourFavorite('michael'))` it will always print the same title, which is the last one in the javascript object (denise).

Ex:

```
console.log(findYourFavorite('michael'))
ford
```

It is not working randomly, as it should, I hope I'm explaining myself, if You need further clarification please do let me know.

Comment: Right.... because you are overlaying the value of `response` ever iteration.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: How do you want this to behave?

Comment: Your `findYourFavorite` function does not take any parameters, which is already a flaw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition `if(input[x].title) {` makes no sense - *all* the titles are truthy. Only assign to `response` if the title is equal to the parameter (which you also need to define).

```js
var input = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'michael',
        favorite: 'bmw'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'steve',
        favorite: 'bentley'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'denise',
        favorite: 'ford'
    },
];

const findYourFavorite = function(titleToFind) {
    for(let x=0; x<3; x++) {
        if(input[x].title === titleToFind) {
            var response = input[x].favorite
            return response;
        }
    }
}
console.log(findYourFavorite('denise'))
```

Or, much more concisely, use `.find`:

```js
var input = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'michael',
        favorite: 'bmw'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'steve',
        favorite: 'bentley'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'denise',
        favorite: 'ford'
    },
];

const findYourFavorite = (titleToFind) => input
  .find(({ title }) => title === titleToFind)
  .favorite;
console.log(findYourFavorite('denise'))
```